# GLSL sampler2DShadow deprecated past version 120? What to use?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've been trying to implement percentage closer filtering for my shadow mapping as described here [Nvidia GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch11.html)

When I try to sample my shadow map using a uniform sampler2DShadow and shadow2D or shadow2DProj the GLSL compile fails and gives me the error

```
shadow2D deprecated after version 120
```

How would I go about implementing an equivalent solution in GLSL 330+? I'm currently just using a binary texture sample along with Poisson Sampling but the staircase aliasing is pretty bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your title is way off base. `sampler2DShadow` is ***not*** deprecated. The only thing that changed in GLSL 1.30 was that the mess of functions like `texture1D`, `texture2D`, `textureCube`, `shadow2D`, etc. were all replaced with overloads of [`texture (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/texture.xml).

---

#### Note that this overload of `texture (...)` is equivalent to `shadow2D (...)`:

```c
float texture(sampler2DShadow sampler,
              vec3 P,
              [float bias]);
```

The texture coordinates used for the lookup using this overload are: `P.st` and the *reference* value used for depth comparison is `P.r`. This overload only works properly when texture comparison is enabled (`GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE` == `GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE​`) for the texture/sampler object bound to the shadow sampler's texture image unit; otherwise the results are undefined.

---

Beginning with GLSL 1.30, the only time you need to use a different texture lookup function is when you are doing something fundamentally different (e.g. texture projection => `textureProj`, requesting an exact LOD => `textureLod`, fetching a texel by its integer coordinates/sample index => `texelFetch`, etc.). Texture lookup with comparison (shadow sampler) is ***not*** considered fundamentally different enough to require its own specialized texture lookup function.

This is all described quite thoroughly on [OpenGL's wiki site](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)).

Comment: Thank you I had seen this and had GLSL give me an error that the global function wasn't visible but I was setting    GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE == GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE​ after compiling the shader. I hadn't realized it was required to expose that function overload. I'll read more thoroughly next time.

Comment: Isn't P.r (like P.rgb) the same as P.s? (P.stpq)? Shouldn't that be P.p or P.z?