# (OpenGL ShadowMap)Shadow cast on incorrect faces

Tags: opengl, glsl

Here is the demo image:

[image: shadow twice]
[image: shadow on wrong faces]

(Left top 256x256 rect is the depth texture)

I render the shadow map in the first pass(with parallel projection),

then render the scene in the second pass,

then render the scene with shadow map in the final pass.

the shadow is sometimes rendered twice or on the wrong surfaces

Is there any solution?

Full code here:

```
typedef struct
{
    vec3_t org;//origin
    vec3_t off;//position offset
    vec3_t ang;//angle
    float dist;//radius
    int w;//default 512
    int h;//default 512
    int depth;//depth texture
    int color;//color texture
    int dimension;//default = 8
    float mvmatrix[16];
    float projmatrix[16];
    cl_entity_t *followent;
    int inuse;
}sdlight_t;

void R_RenderDepthMap()
{
    qglPolygonOffset( 5.0, 0.0 );
    qglEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    if(cursdlight->followent)
    {
        VectorCopy(cursdlight->followent->origin, cursdlight->org);
    }

    qglMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    qglLoadIdentity();
    qglOrtho(-cursdlight->w / cursdlight->dimension, cursdlight->w / cursdlight->dimension, -cursdlight->h / cursdlight->dimension, cursdlight->h / cursdlight->dimension, -9999, 9999);//cursdlight->dist

    qglMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    qglLoadIdentity();

    qglRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
    qglRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);
    qglRotatef(-cursdlight->ang[2], 1, 0, 0);
    qglRotatef(-cursdlight->ang[0], 0, 1, 0);
    qglRotatef(-cursdlight->ang[1], 0, 0, 1);
    qglTranslatef(-cursdlight->org[0], -cursdlight->org[1], -cursdlight->org[2]);

    qglViewport(0, 0, cursdlight->w, cursdlight->h);

    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, cursdlight->projmatrix);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, cursdlight->mvmatrix);

    qglDepthRange(1.0, 0.0);
    qglDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    qglEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //qglCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    qglClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    qglClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Render Models..
    R_DrawEntitiesOnList();

    qglDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    qglBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, s_BackBufferFBO.s_hBackBufferFBO);
    qglActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0);
    qglBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cursdlight->depth);
    qglCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 0, 0, cursdlight->w, cursdlight->h, 0);
}

void R_SetupShadowLight(void)
{
    // enable automatic texture coordinates generation
    GLfloat planeS[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    GLfloat planeT[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    GLfloat planeR[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};
    GLfloat planeQ[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

    // setup texture stages
    qglActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);
    qglBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cursdlight->depth);

    qglTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE_ARB, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC_ARB, GL_LEQUAL);
    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE_ARB, GL_INTENSITY);

    qglEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    qglEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    qglEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);
    qglEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

    qglTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR); 
    qglTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, planeS);
    qglTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR); 
    qglTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_EYE_PLANE, planeT);
    qglTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR); 
    qglTexGenfv(GL_R, GL_EYE_PLANE, planeR);
    qglTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR); 
    qglTexGenfv(GL_Q, GL_EYE_PLANE, planeQ);

    // load texture projection matrix
    qglMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    qglLoadIdentity();

    qglTranslatef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    qglScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    qglMultMatrixf(cursdlight->projmatrix);
    qglMultMatrixf(cursdlight->mvmatrix);

    qglMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    if (gl_polyoffset->value)
    {
        qglEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
        qglPolygonOffset(-1, -gl_polyoffset->value);
    }

    qglDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    qglEnable(GL_BLEND);
    qglBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
    qglColor4f(1,1,1,1);

    qglUseProgramObjectARB(shadow_program);
    qglUniform1iARB(shadow_uniform.shadowmap, 0);
}

void R_FinishShadowLight(void)
{
    qglUseProgramObjectARB(0);

    if (gl_polyoffset->value)
    {
        qglDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    }
    qglDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    qglDisable(GL_BLEND);

    qglActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);

    qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE_ARB, GL_NONE);

    qglMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    qglLoadIdentity();

    qglDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    qglDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    qglDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);
    qglDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

    qglMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void R_DrawShadows(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numsdlights; i++)
    {
        cursdlight = &sdlights[i];

        if(!R_ShouldCastShadow())
            continue;

        R_SetupShadowLight();
        R_DrawSceneShadow();
        R_FinishShadowLight();
    }
}
```

GLSL part:

```
//vertex shader
varying vec4 shadowcoord;

void main()
{
    shadowcoord = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}

//fragment shader
#version 120
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowmap;
varying vec4 shadowcoord;

uniform float xoffset = 1.0/512.0;
uniform float yoffset = 1.0/512.0;

float lookup(vec4 coord, vec2 offSet)
{
    return shadow2DProj(shadowmap, coord + vec4(offSet.x * xoffset, offSet.y * yoffset, 0.0, 0.0) ).w;
}

void main()
{
    float shadow;
    shadow = lookup(shadowcoord, vec2(0.0,0.0)) + lookup(shadowcoord, vec2(0.035,0.0)) + lookup(shadowcoord, vec2(-0.035,0.0)) + lookup(shadowcoord, vec2(0.0,0.035)) + lookup(shadowcoord, vec2(0.0,-0.035));
    shadow /= 5.0;

    if(shadow == 1.0)
        discard;
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, (1.0-shadow) * 0.5);
}
```

Comment: your shadow texture coord miss the inverse model view transformation (transformation applied between shadow map computation and individual object positioning) `ShadowCoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] *  invModelView * gl_ModelViewMatrix) * gl_Vertex;`

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.

Comment: I had an idea that we can compare shadowmap's depth and gl_Vertex.xyz's depth in light view space, if the depth value of gl_Vertex's is much smaller than shadowmap's, it means the surface with shadow is much far away from the entity.

Comment: ShadowMap lookup makes the depth comparison, check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877938/glsl-sampler2dshadow-deprecated-past-version-120-what-to-use), and maybe review different examples, here is a good one: (http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/#Using_the_shadow_map)